# ActiveMQ: Get list of connections through JMX?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

How do I get the list of the connections to the OpenWire connector of ActiveMQ?
JConsole is able to list the connections, but I don't see which "view" I can use to get the list:

Example ObjectName of a connection:
`org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Connection,ConnectorName=openwire,Connection=toto`

I tried "ConnectorViewMBean", but the operations on it don't allow me to list the connections:

```java
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Connection,ConnectorName=openwire"); 
mbsc.getMBeanInfo(name); 
ConnectorViewMBean view = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbsc, name, ConnectorViewMBean.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was the usage of an expression:

```
ObjectName connectionNames = 
      new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost," + 
                     "Type=Connection,ConnectorName=openwire,Connection=*");

Set<ObjectName> names = mbsc.queryNames(connectionNames, null); 
for(ObjectName name : names) { 
   logger.error("Name: "+name.getCanonicalName()); 
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to format code correctly?? SHIFT + ENTER creates a new block code, ENTER too ...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help or use the toolbar buttons in the editor

Comment: This answer is correct for ActiveMQ 5.7.0 and before.  The format of the ObjectName changed in ActiveMQ 5.8.0, as documented in the [5.8.0 release notes](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-580-release.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.14.5, which uses a different ObjectName format for querying connections via JMX. The equivalent to [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7434284/4548231) in this version of ActiveMQ is:

```java
final JMXServiceURL url       = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
final JMXConnector  connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
connector.connect();

final ObjectName connectionName = new ObjectName(
    "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker," +
    "brokerName=localhost,"            +
    "connector=clientConnectors,"      +
    "connectorName=openwire,"          +
    "connectionViewType=clientId,"     +
    "connectionName=*"
);

final MBeanServerConnection mbsc  = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
final Set<ObjectName>       names = mbsc.queryNames(connectionName, null);
for (final ObjectName name : names) {
    System.out.println(name.getCanonicalName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent versions of ActiveMQ (5.1x.x), you can use the [BrokerViewMBean](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/BrokerViewMBean.html) to get a map of transport connectors:

```
Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<>();
String[] creds = {brokerUsername, brokerPassword};
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);

final String managementURL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi";
try (JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(managementURL, env)) {
   ObjectName on = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
   BrokerViewMBean broker = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connector.getMBeanServerConnection(), on, BrokerViewMBean.class, false);
   Map<String, String> transportConnectors = broker.getTransportConnectors();
   // broker.getTransportConnectorsByType("tcp"); // openwire
   // broker.addConnector(String discoveryAddress);
   // broker.removeConnector(String connectorName);
 } catch (MalformedObjectNameException ex) {
    // log error
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    // log error
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    // log error
 }
```

Check also out [ConnectorViewMBean](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/ConnectorViewMBean.html).

However, while there are methods in `BrokerViewMBean` to get transport connectors, as demonstrated in the above code, there aren't any to get a list of network (a.k.a. broker-to-broker) connectors.