# ActiveMQ: Get list of network connections through JMX?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

How do I get a list of **network** connectors of a ActiveMQ broker via JMX? [This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431734/activemq-get-list-of-connections-through-jmx) answers how to get a list of transport (a.k.a. client) connectors, however, even if [BrokerViewMBean](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/BrokerViewMBean.html) provides a way to get a list of transport connectors via JMX:

```
brokerViewMBean.getTransportConnectors();
```

there isn't an equivalent

```
brokerViewMBean.getNetworkConnectors();
```

even though there are:

```
brokerViewMBean.addNetworkConnector(String discoveryAddress);
brokerViewMBean.removeNetworkConnector(String connectorName) ;
```

A list of network connectors can be retrieved via [BrokerService](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerService.html),

```
NetworkConnector    getNetworkConnectorByName(String connectorName) 
List<NetworkConnector>  getNetworkConnectors() 
String[]    getNetworkConnectorURIs()
```

but, if I 'm not mistaken, BrokerService starts an embedded ActiveMQ, it is not a JMX API.

Answer (score 0):

The JMX MBean currently doesn't support this but there is an open [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8196) created by the author of this question to add those APIs.  This will require code changes and a new broker release before becoming available.